# How to receive a file(ie. a text file) from a http post in php?

Tags: php, http, httpwebrequest

I am sending a file from `client(C#)` using `webclient` or `HttpWebRequest`. I like to know to how to receive the file sent from client in `PHP(Server)` . 
               I have checked `$_POST`, its empty.

**Client code (c#) :**

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
 client.UploadFile("http://path/file.php","POST",@"Data.txt");
}
```

Comment: Try looking at [this](http://www.tech-juice.org/2011/02/11/upload-a-file-with-c-to-a-php-page/) and see if it will help.  You don't display what errors you are getting back with your code, so debugging it is impossible without it. ^^

Comment: Thanks for the link..(it solved my issue) (I'm just getting 'permission denied' error. which is also because of lack of permission in server path)

Comment: You are welcome ^^  The permission denied error - is that coming from the C# or the PHP return?  If from the PHP, make sure that it has write-access to the directory you are trying to write to (or the file, if going to be overwriting it).

Comment: from the php. And yes, Its due to the lack of permission to that directory.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, `$_POST` will be empty, you should check `$_FILES` variable for uploaded files:
Here is quick snippet:

```
<?php
$uploaddir = "uploads/";
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile))
{
  echo "The file has been uploaded successfully";
}
else
{
  echo "There was an error uploading the file";
}
?>
```

The contents of $_FILES from above script is as follows.

**$_FILES['file']['name']** The original name of the file on the client machine.

**$_FILES['file']['type']** The mime type of the file, if the browser provided this information. An example would be “image/gif”.

**$_FILES['file']['size']** The size, in bytes, of the uploaded file.

**$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']** The temporary filename of the file in which the uploaded file was stored on the server.

**$_FILES['file']['error']** Since PHP 4.2.0, PHP returns an appropriate following error code along with the file array

- UPLOAD_ERR_OK – Value: 0; There is no error, the file uploaded with
  success.
- UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the
  upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.
- UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE Value: 2; The uploaded file exceeds the
  MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form.
- UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL Value: 3; The uploaded file was only partially
  uploaded.
- UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE Value: 4; No file was uploaded.

Uploaded Files will by default be stored in the server’s default temporary directory. Variable **$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']** will hold the info about where it is stored. The move_uploaded_file function needs to be used to store the uploaded file to the correct location

Comment: I want to make sure that it's noted that if you use this, you want to make sure you check file type and all that good stuff on the server side to make sure no one uploads anything malicious. (Even if you check it client side as anything can be POSTed to the backend ^^)

Comment: Thanks.But, its not getting uploaded.I've added my client side code also now.

Comment: The link mentioned in Jon's comment, solved the issue. But, its nearly same as that of yours. Can you please check the [link](http://www.tech-juice.org/2011/02/11/upload-a-file-with-c-to-a-php-page/) and let me know the difference,as i can mark this as answer then.

Comment: well, difference is `myFileVariable` should be `file` (var_dump() would show that, as i didn't knew exact variable name), and more checking in server side, like **is_uploaded_file()**. I dont know what should be done more, as you problems was that you were checking wrong PHP variable ($_POST) for file. Files are uploaded to $_FILES

Answer (score 3):

**You should use the below code as your reference:**

```
    if(isset($_FILES['file']['name']) && !empty($_FILES['file']['name']))
    {
    $name=$_FILES['file']['name'];
    
    $size=$_FILES['file']['size'];
    $type=$_FILES['file']['type'];
    $tmp_name=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $error=$_FILES['file']['error'];
    $maxsize ="Your size limit";
    $location='Your location to upload file';

    // perform any security check here...

   if($size <= $maxsize)
    {
     if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location.$name))
        {
          // perform your operation down here
        }
    }

   }
```

**Note: -** $_FILES['file']['name'] in this line file stands for the name of form file field.

Comment: use $maxsize instead of maxsize in the 2nd if condition